# jdk11 HttpClient return 400 after sending multiple post requests

Tags: java

I use jdk11 HttpClient send msg which from file,and Send once per line。but about 40 times . 400 statusCode is appearing. i don't know why? thanks for your suggestions

Below is my source：

> SendMsgHttp.java

```java
//ignorance other source
 public void sendData(String rawHex,String versionType){
        String json_data =  key_protocolType+versionType+ key_upLinkData+rawHex+key_reqTimestamp;
        System.out.println("send data："+json_data);
        HttpRequest request =  httpRequestBuilder
                .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .header("Authorization","Basic Y21kdDpDbUR0MTIzJA==")
                .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(json_data))
                .build();
        try {
            HttpResponse response= client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
            System.out.println(response.statusCode());
            atomicNum.addAndGet(1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

> ReadFileAndSendThread.java

```java
public class ReadFileAndSendThread implements  Runnable{
    private SendMsgHttp sendMsgHttp ;
    private  File file;
    private CountDownLatch latch;
    public ReadFileAndSendThread( File file,SendMsgHttp sendMsgHttp,CountDownLatch latch){
        this.file = file;
        this.sendMsgHttp = sendMsgHttp;
        this.latch = latch;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            readSingleHandle();
            latch.countDown();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("go on");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void  readSingleHandle() throws IOException {
        InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
StandardOpenOption.READ);
        String tempString;
        while ((tempString = br.readLine()) != null) {
            try {
                String[] strData = tempString.split("\\|");
                String rawData  = strData[3].trim();
                String versionType = strData[2].trim();
                if(null !=rawData&&!rawData.equals("")
                   && null !=versionType&&!versionType.equals("")){
                    sendMsgHttp.sendData(rawData,versionType);
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        br.close();
    }

}
```

> main  SendMain.java

```java
public class SendMain {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        ExecutorService threadPool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 25,
                0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                new LinkedBlockingQueue());
        String path = new File("").getAbsolutePath()+"/export";//"/root/xzg/send/exportdata";
        File[] fs = new File(path).listFiles();
        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(fs.length);
        for(File file:fs){
            threadPool.execute(new ReadFileAndSendThread(file,
                    new SendMsgHttp("http://localhost:9997/xxx")
            ,latch));
        }
        threadPool.shutdown();
        try {
            latch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("count nums："+SendMsgHttp.getSendCount());
    }
}
```

**and the file content like this**
[image]

At last i run it. the result like below

```
//ok
response.statusCode:200
response.statusCode:200
response.statusCode:200
response.statusCode:200
response.statusCode:400
response.statusCode:400
response.statusCode:400
//always 400 ??? this wrong is happend
```

According to the result  i find the first 47 data always were successful, and the rest failed.And  Running many times, the results are the same

and i try sending the data which return "response.statusCode:400" and it's ok(response.statusCode:200)

what's going on? need u help . Thanks again.

Comment: You get a 400 status code because that's what the server decided to send back as a result. If it's well-designed, you should have an error message explaining the problem in the body of the response. Print it.

Comment: @JBNizet i'm sorry the body of respons is empty when the statusCode is 400 . and i find if i send data 47 times by HttpClient object then create a new httpclient replace it .it works ok